# sizeof empty string in C#

Tags: c#, string

In Java, an empty string is 40 bytes. In Python it's 20 bytes. How big is an empty string object in C#? I cannot do `sizeof`, and I don't know how else to find out. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[It's 18 bytes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/strings.aspx):

> 16 bytes of memory + 2 bytes per character allocated + 2 bytes for the final null character.

Note that this was written about .Net 1.1.

The `m_ArrayLength` field was removed in .Net 4.0 (you can see this in the reference source)

Comment: Any way to test this? How on earth do I find out programatically?

Comment: Or 26 bytes on a 64-bit system, and don't forget alignment.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm on Linux, but thanks, good idea. Isn't it interesting that I cannot find out within C#? Java and Python were easy...

Comment: @Random: How can anything take 26 bytes on a 64-bit system? 26 bytes isn't even a valid size for a 32-bit system.

Comment: It should not vary at all on a 64-bit system.  Note that this doesn't include the object header, will Jon Skeet did measure and which will vary.

Comment: It isn't accurate for .NET 4.0 anymore.  And object sizes are always a multiple of 4, thus 20 bytes.

Comment: I meant the size before alignment padding. (and, are they always a multiple of 8 on 64-bit?)

Answer (score 6):

The CLR version matters.  Prior to .NET 4, a string object had an extra 4-byte field that stored the "capacity", m_arrayLength field.  That field is no longer around in .NET 4.  It otherwise has the standard object header, 4 bytes for the sync-block, 4 bytes for the method table pointer.  Then 4 bytes to store the string length (m_stringLength), followed by 2 bytes each for each character in the string.  And a 0 char to make it compatible with native code.  Objects are always a multiple of 4 bytes long, minimum 16 bytes.

An empty string is thus 4 + 4 + 4 + 2 = 14 bytes, rounded up to 16 bytes on .NET 4.0.  20 bytes on earlier versions.  Given values are for x86.  This is all very visible in the debugger, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240971/where-does-net-place-the-string-value/5241493#5241493) for hints.

Comment: Appreciate it, thanks. Why did you say that "most likely mono will have 4 more bytes"?

Comment: Because it was based on SSCLI20 which in turn was based on the source code for the version 2 CLR.

Comment: So the `m_arrayLength` is still there?

Comment: Presumably.  Getting the source code for Mono is easy, why don't you have a look if the debugger isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Jon Skeet recently wrote a whole [article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/) on the subject.

On x86, an empty string is 16 bytes, and on x64 it's 32 bytes

Comment: What about the null character that @SLaks talks about? Is that necessary?

Comment: @Dervin Thunk, no idea... read the article for more details ;)

Comment: 16 bytes is correct for .NET 4.0 x86, the zero terminator fits.  Up to three chars, the next larger string is one with 4 characters, 20 bytes.  Mono is most likely 4 bytes bigger.