# How to Represent Conjugation Tables in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, struct

I'm designing a linguistic analyzer for French text. I have a dictionary in XML format, that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Dictionary>
  <!--This is the base structure for every entry in the dictionary. Values on attributes are given
    as explanations for the attributes. Though this is the structure of the finished product for each word, definition, context and context examples will be ommitted as they don't have a real effect on the application at this moment. Defini-->
  <Word word="The word in the dictionary (any word that would be defined)." aspirate="Whether or not the word starts with an aspirate h. Some adjectives that come before words that start with a non-aspirate h have an extra form (AdjectiveForms -&gt; na [non-aspirate]).">
      <GrammaticalForm form="The grammatical form of the word is the grammatical context in which it is used. Forms may consist of a word in noun, adjective, adverb, exclamatory or other form. Each form (generally) has its own definition, as the meaning of the word changes in the way it is used.">
        <Definition definition=""></Definition>
      </GrammaticalForm>
    <ConjugationTables>
      <NounForms ms="The masculin singular form of the noun." fs="The feminin singular form of the noun." mpl="The masculin plural form of the noun." fpl="The feminin plural form of the noun." gender="The gender of the noun. Determines"></NounForms>
      <AdjectiveForms ms="The masculin singular form of the adjective." fs="The feminin singular form of the adjective." mpl="The masculin plural form of the adjective." fpl="The feminin plural form of the adjective." na="The non-aspirate form of the adjective, in the case where the adjective is followed by a non-aspirate word." location="Where the adjective is placed around the noun (before, after, or both)."></AdjectiveForms>
      <VerbForms group="What group the verb belongs to (1st, 2nd, 3rd or exception)." auxillary="The auxillary verb taken by the verb." prepositions="A CSV list of valid prepositions this verb uses; for grammatical analysis." transitive="Whether or not the verb is transitive." pronominal="The pronominal infinitive form of the verb, if the verb allows pronominal construction.">
        <Indicative>
          <Present fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></Present>
          <SimplePast fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></SimplePast>
          <PresentPerfect fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></PresentPerfect>
          <PastPerfect fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></PastPerfect>
          <Imperfect fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></Imperfect>
          <Pluperfect fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></Pluperfect>
          <Future fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></Future>
          <PastFuture fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></PastFuture>
        </Indicative>
        <Subjunctive>
          <Present fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></Present>
          <Past fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></Past>
          <Imperfect fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></Imperfect>
          <Pluperfect fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></Pluperfect>
        </Subjunctive>
        <Conditional>
          <Present fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></Present>
          <FirstPast fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></FirstPast>
          <SecondPast fps="(Je) first person singular." sps="(Tu) second person singular." tps="(Il) third person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural." tpp="(Ils) third person plural."></SecondPast>
        </Conditional>
        <Imperative>
          <Present sps="(Tu) second person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural."></Present>
          <Past sps="(Tu) second person singular." fpp="(Nous) first person plural." spp="(Vous) second person plural."></Past>
        </Imperative>
        <Infinitive present="The present infinitive form of the verb." past="The past infinitive form of the verb."></Infinitive>
        <Participle present="The present participle of the verb." past="The past partciple of the verb."></Participle>
      </VerbForms>
    </ConjugationTables>
  </Word>
</Dictionary>
```

Sorry it's so long, but it's necessary to show exactly how the data is modeled (tree-node structure).

Currently I am using `structs` to model the conjugation tables, nested `structs` to be more specific. Here is the class I created to model what is *a single entry* in the XML file:

```
class Word
{
    public string word { get; set; }
    public bool aspirate { get; set; }
    public List<GrammaticalForms> forms { get; set; }

    struct GrammaticalForms
    {
        public string form { get; set; }
        public string definition { get; set; }
    }

    struct NounForms
    {
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string masculinSingular { get; set; }
        public string femininSingular { get; set; }
        public string masculinPlural { get; set; }
        public string femininPlural { get; set; }
    }

    struct AdjectiveForms
    {
        public string masculinSingular { get; set; }
        public string femininSingular { get; set; }
        public string masculinPlural { get; set; }
        public string femininPlural { get; set; }
        public string nonAspirate { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
    }

    struct VerbForms
    {
        public string group { get; set; }
        public string auxillary { get; set; }
        public string[] prepositions { get; set; }
        public bool transitive { get; set; }
        public string pronominalForm { get; set; }

        struct IndicativePresent
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativeSimplePast
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativePresentPerfect
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativePastPerfect
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativeImperfect
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativePluperfect
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativeFuture
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativePastFuture
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }

        struct SubjunctivePresent
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct SubjunctivePast
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct SubjunctiveImperfect
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct SubjunctivePluperfect
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }

        struct ConditionalPresent
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct ConditionalFirstPast
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct ConditionalSecondPast
        {
            public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }

        struct ImperativePresent
        {
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }
        struct ImperativePast
        {
            public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
            public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
            public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
        }

        struct Infinitive
        {
            public string present { get; set; }
            public string past { get; set; }
        }

        struct Participle
        {
            public string present { get; set; }
            public string past { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I'm new to C#, and I'm not too familiar with the data structures. Based on my limited knowledge of C++, I know that `structs` are useful when you are modeling small, highly-related pieces of data, which is why I am currently using them in this fashion.

All of these structs could realistically be made into a *ConjugationTables* `class`, and would have, to a high degree, the same structure. I'm unsure of whether to make these into a class, or use a different data structure that would be better suited to the problem. In order to give some more information about the problem specifications, I'll say the following:

1. Once these values have been loaded from the XML file, they will **not be changed**.
2. These values will be **read/fetched very often**.
3. The table-like structure **must be maintained** - that is to say that `IndicativePresent` must be nested under `VerbForms`; the same applies to all other structs that are members of the `VerbForms` struct. These are conjugation **tables** after all!
4. **Perhaps the most important**: I need the organization of the data to be set up in a way that, if for example a `Word` in the XML file does not have a `GrammaticalForm` of ***verb***, that no `VerbForms` struct will actually be created for that entry. This is in an effort to improve efficiency - why instantiate `VerbForms` if the word is not actually a verb? This idea of avoiding unnecessary creation of these "forms" tables (which are currently represented as `struct XXXXXForms`) is absolutely imperative.

---

In accordance with (primarily) point **#4** above, what kinds of data structures would be best used in modeling conjugation **tables** (not *database* tables)? Do I need to change the format of my data in order to be compliant with #4? If I instantiate a `new Word`, will the structs, in their current state, be instantiated as well and take up a lot of space? Here's some math... after Googling around and eventually finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690922/sizeof-empty-string-in-c-sharp)...

In all the conjugation tables (nouns, adjectives, verbs), there are a total of (coincidence?) **100** `string`s allocated, and that are empty. So **100** x **18** bytes = **1800 bytes** for each `Word`, at minimum, if these data structures are created and remain empty (there will always be at least some overhead for the values that would actually be filled in). So assuming (just randomly, could be more or less) **50,000** `Word`s that would need to be in memory, that's **90 million bytes**, or approximately **85.8307** megabytes.

That's a lot of overhead just to have empty tables. So what is a way that I can put this data together to allow me to instantiate **only certain tables (noun, adjective, verb)** depending on *what `GrammaticalForms` the `Word` actually has* (in the XML file).

I want these tables to be a member of the `Word` class, but only instantiate the tables that I need. I can't think of a way around it, and now that I did the math on the `structs` I know that it's not a good solution. My first thought is to make a class for each type of `NounForms`, `AdjectiveForms`, and `VerbForms`, and instantiate the class if the form appears in the XML file. I'm not sure if that is correct though...

Any suggestions?

Comment: As for structs, your classes are both too mutable and too large to qualify as a good use-case for structs (among other reasons).

Comment: In your example you have never used the struct IndicativePresent. Why is that? Incomplete? Or maybe you are misunderstanding C# a little due to your C# background. Make yourself familiar with the difference between classes and structs in .NET. This determines the storage location (heap vs. inline).; I think your use case of structs is good because you have high performance standards and structs can help here reduce indirection, memory usage and GC pressure.

Comment: I never actually use any of the structs in the code I gave, only because I'm still deciding on how to manage the data itself. If the `Word` in the XML has a `GrammaticalForm` of **verb**, then the `VerbForms` table would need to be populated. Same for **noun** and **adjective**. Since I'm not sure how to structure the data, I didn't actually give an example of it being populated. The main concern of mine is *load time* of the data.  Because the XML file will likely be several megabytes when it is finished (50,000+ `Word`s), whatever populates the fastest is preferable - `class` or `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. I'd switch to using class.
2. I'd name the class in the singular and express cardinality through the property name.
3. I'd remove the nesting from the class definitions.
4. It looks like you can introduce a ConjugationForm abstract class, have multiple ConjugationForm subclasses (NounForm, AdjectiveForm, abstract VerbForm, then all the VerbForm subclasses - IndicativePresent, IndicativeSimplePast, etc.) The Word class then has a data structure for the ConjugationForm instances, maybe `List<ConjugationForm> conjugationTable {get; set;}`

As for the memory / GC pressure, have you actually measured how bad the situation is? I'd recommend coding up something and actually testing to verify whether you're going to experience GC problems, rather than trying to guess or make an assumption. The GC is pretty well optimized to allocate and de-allocate a lot of small objects, but long lived and/or large objects might cause you problems.

Comment: Gordon, yhank you for your answer. I do like the idea of a single `ConjugationForm` abstract class, but honestly I have no idea how to implement that in c#. I started programming with Java, but I never really got into inheritance, interfaces and all that. Do you think you could give me an example of how that might look? As for the massive amount of objects in memory that I'll be dealing with - there will eventually be about **50,000** `Word` objects in a `SortedDictionary`, so I'm trying to optimize these tables (classes) as much as possible in preparation for that.

Comment: just declare public abstract class ConjugationForm { }. You can put fields, properties, methods, etc. like a normal class. abstract tells the compiler that you can't instantiate a ConjugationForm, so it's a way to say that only the subclasses are things you can instatniate. I don't think 50K objects is really massive. It's always better IMO to put off optimization until you've proven that you need it.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for your answer and comments - I've decided that an abstract class and derived subclasses definitely make more sense here. I didn't understand them before now, but with some more research and help from a prof I was able to get it working as desired :)

Answer (score 2):

I would change to using classes since everything in your data is a string and you have so much nesting.  Having structs doesn't buy you anything for what you are trying to do.

Also, I would recommend creating base classes for each hierarchy and either just use a single class for each level (with some indication of what type it is) or use inheritance to create each class.  Using a single base class allows you to reduce your code making it more maintainable and much easier to read.

Example.  Instead of having all of those structs under your verbforms, you could have something like this:

```
enum VerbConjugationType
{
    IndicativePresent,
    IndicativeSimplePast,
    ...
}

class VerbConjugation
{
    public VerbConjugationType ConjugationType { get; set; }
    public string FirstPersonSingular { get; set; }
    public string SecondPersonSingular { get; set; }
    public string ThirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
    public string FirstPersonPlural { get; set; }
    public string SecondPersonPlural { get; set; }
    public string ThirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, as it greatly simplifies the problem. However, this would only work for about 70% of the `VerbForms`. For example, `IndicativePresent` has all 6 of these forms, but `Infinitive` does not. As a matter of fact, `Infinitive` has only *present* and *past*, which aren't the same as `IndicativePresent`, which has *firstPersonSingular* --> *thirdPersonPlural*. This is a good structure, but is there a way to effectively handle those edge cases of having different *forms* per type? They won't ever *change*, so it wouldn't be a bad idea to just hard-code all the types... I think.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll clear up a misunderstanding that might exist:

```
struct Outer {
 struct Inner {
  int X;
 }
}

Outer o;
```

This does not allocate any storage because `Inner` is never used.

```
struct Outer {
 struct Inner {
  int X;
 }
 Inner i;
}

Outer o;
```

This allocates 4 bytes of storage (generally). The nesting of structs changes nothing. It is purely an organisational instrument.

In your data structures you have never created a field of most types which is why I cannot totally see what you intended. Maybe you just misunderstood how struct instances are created because you are coming from a C++ background.

---

> I need the organization of the data to be set up in a way that, if for example a Word in the XML file does not have a `GrammaticalForm` of verb, that no `VerbForms` struct will actually be created for that entry.

For that you'd need `VerbForms` to be a class so that it always lives on the heap and the object reference to it can be `null`.

> If I instantiate a new Word, will the structs, in their current state, be instantiated as well and take up a lot of space?

Yes, see above. Nested structs are inlined into the runtime object layout. All fields have constant offsets. Making fields nullable would not change that. It would add an additional boolean.

> So what is a way that I can put this data together to allow me to instantiate only certain tables (noun, adjective, verb) depending on what GrammaticalForms the Word actually has (in the XML file).

Probably just put them on the heap, i.e. make them a `class`.

You seem to be worried about load performance, not about memory usage. In that sense all your optimizations do not really help. Reading and parsing XML is by far more expensive than creating objects from it. Also, you will have big GC costs.

The cost of a G2 collection is proportional to the number of references, objects and heap size (in approximation). You will produce tons of garbage and long-lived objects. You will have tons of G2 collections.

If you insist on more efficient storage, you could have a global array for each of the value types you are using. When you want to reference an instance you store its index in the global array. This reduces the number of heap-allocated objects and makes the pointer structure faster to traverse for the GC. http://marcgravell.blogspot.de/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html

So instead of

```
class VerbForms...
..
public VerbForms VerbForms { get; set; } //nullable reference to heap object
```

you have

```
struct VerbForms...
...
List<VerbForms> verbFormsGlobal = new List<VerbForms>(); //stores *all* VerbForms
...
public int? VerbFormsIndex { get; set; } //no reference, no GC cost
```

Comment: thank you for clearing up the confusion with `structs`! I will likely make the conjugations tables (all the `Forms`) into classes, perhaps even one abstract class as Gordon suggested in his answer (as soon as I figure out how to do that!). However, I suppose that I don't understand the `global array` that you're talking about. The plan is to load each `Word` from the XML file, and create a `Word` object from it that has a similar structure. These `Word` objects, as they are loaded will be placed into a `SortedDictionary`. If all the references live there, they shouldn't be GC'd... right?

Comment: The GC remarks of mine are not about correctness. They are about perf. In C++ allocated objects and pointers to not have any cost by themselves. In .NET they slow down the GC. See my edit. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21508199/revisions

Comment: Ah I see - that could actually be useful. However, the only problem is that in a linguistic sense, it's much easier to have, say, `IndicativePresent` be a member of a `VerbForms` class, so that I could access members like: `verbForms.indicativePresent.firstPersonSingular`, which would give me that specific conjugation in context. With your approach, I think I would need to traverse the `verbFormsGlobal` list when looking for a specific conjugation, and in the end I think that **O(n)** operation adds up to be costly. In the method I described, lookup would be O(1). At least that's what I think!

Comment: You store an index to the right element in `VerbFormsIndex`, so that it is O(1). This is an advanced technique. You might or might not want to use it. Maybe you can just make everything a class and see if perf is ok for you. If yes, you're done. If no, invest effort into optimizations.

Comment: I am currently working on abstracting some of the data so that it is more efficient. Even with the entire dictionary loaded I don't think I'll surpass more than 25 MB of RAM, but it's necessary for the entire `Dictionary` to be in memory for the application to be effective in analyzing text. As for your suggestion, this does seem advanced. I think I understand the concept. In the future would it be difficult to change references from a `class VerbForms` to your model as an optimization? Theoretically the data would be laid out the same, it would just be `class` vs `struct` at that point.

Comment: Yes, that would impact all code accessing this piece of data. You now need to pass around the global array to any method that needs to consume verb forms. Changes like this one impact a lot of code in a viral way.; With 25MB of data, maybe the best answer to this question is: don't optimize at all.

Comment: Alright, in that case I'll stick with my original plan for simplicity's sake, since I'm still new to C#. If need be, I'll spend a week refactoring in the future if the optimization is needed. Thanks :)