# A Good Use Case for an Consolidated Class in c#?

Tags: c#, enums

I have 3 classes of conjugation tables - one for *nouns*, *adjectives* and *verbs*. As suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21504604/1986871) to a previous question of mine, it would be greatly beneficial to have a base class for the **verbs**, and use an `Enum` to have all the actual conjugation **types**, so that I could distinguish between instances of the class. The `Enum` would look like this:

```
enum VerbConjugationType
{
    IndicativePresent,
    Participle,
    // etc
}
```

and the `VerbConjugation` class:

```
class VerbConjugation
{
    public VerbConjugationType conjugationType { get; set; }
    public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
    public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
    public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
    public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
    public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
    public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
    public string present { get; set; }
    public string past { get; set; }
}
```

However, there is one slight problem - several of the **types** of verb conjugations don't have the same format, that is to say that `IndicativePresent` looks like this:

```
{
  public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
  public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
  public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
  public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
  public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
  public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
}
```

and `Participle` looks like this:

```
{
  public string present { get; set; }
  public string past { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to have a *single class* `VerbConjugation` that can be instantiated with different *sets* of data depending on the `VerbConjugationType` (which would be an `Enum`)? That is to say, if I instantiate `VerbConjugation` with `VerbConjugationType` of **IndicativePresent**, I want only the data (as shown above) to be members of that *instance* of the class. Same goes for `Participle`; only `string present` and `string past` should be members of that instance.

**Edit**: It would be *preferable* if I could access data members in the following fashion:

`VerbConjugation.Indicative.Present.fps` (first person singular of indicative present)
and
`VerbConjugation.Participle.present` (present participle)

Is there a class/organization method that allows me to do this, even with the differences in *data members* for each conjugation type?

**Another edit**: Here is the code that I currently have, which might give a hint as to my desired structure - what I have doesn't seem like the right approach though:

```
class VerbTable
    {
        public char group { get; set; }
        public char auxillary { get; set; }
        public string[] prepositions { get; set; }
        public bool transitive { get; set; }
        public bool pronominal { get; set; }

        /*
         * The subject of the verb determined by the markers:
         * 'fps' (first person singular)
         * 'sps' (second person singular)
         * 'tps' (third person singular)
         * 'fpp' (first person plural)
         * 'spp' (second person plural)
         * 'tpp' (third person plural)
         * 'present' (present tense)
         * 'past' (past tense)
         * and their accompanying conjugations.
         */

        struct IndicativePresent
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativeSimplePast
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativePresentPerfect
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativePastPerfect
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativeImperfect
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativePluperfect
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativeFuture
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct IndicativePastFuture
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }

        struct SubjunctivePresent
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct SubjunctivePast
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct SubjunctiveImperfect
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct SubjunctivePluperfect
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct ConditionalPresent
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct ConditionalFirstPast
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct ConditionalSecondPast
        {
            public string fps { get; set; }
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string tps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
            public string tpp { get; set; }
        }
        struct ImperativePresent
        {
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
        }
        struct ImperativePast
        {
            public string sps { get; set; }
            public string fpp { get; set; }
            public string spp { get; set; }
        }
        struct Infinitive
        {
            public string present { get; set; }
            public string past { get; set; }
        }
        struct Participle
        {
            public string present { get; set; }
            public string past { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

and this class instance will be a member of the `Word` class like so

```
class Word
{
    // ...
    // Can access a specific conjugation with:
    // Word.VerbTable.IndicatifPresent.fps;
    public VerbTable verbTable { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When faced with similar complexity in the past, I created derived classes for each of the new types. Please see Composite design pattern.

Comment: I think I'd use a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of making classes for `IndicativePresent` and `Participle`, as this is essentially a collection of key value pairs, which may vary even more widely based on other grammatical types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  Don't do this.  Make an abstract base class for `Verb`:

```
abstract class Verb
{
   // You can add in any properties that all Verbs share
}
```

Then create a `IndicativePresent` class:

```
class IndicativePresent : Verb
{
  public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
  public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
  public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
  public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
  public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
  public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
}
```

And a `Participle` class:

```
class Participle : Verb
{
  public string present { get; set; }
  public string past { get; set; }
}
```

Both types will derive from `Verb`, so you'll be able to tell each `is` a verb, however they'll both have different *sets* of properties.  You'll no longer need the `VerbConjugationType` type, as you can simply look at the type of the object:

```
var ip = new IndicativePresent();
var par = new Participle();

(ip is Verb)              // True
(par is Verb)             // True
(ip is IndicativePresent) // True
(par is Participle)       // True
```

Comment: Okay yeah, that was the other solution I was thinking of, but I've never dealt with abstract classes before, and all the documentation on MSDN and Googling was a bit unhelpful in my opinion. There are **19** total verb conjugation types in French though... is this *really* a better idea that just having one `VerbConjugation` class and having each *type* be a `struct` or something similar?

Comment: It doesn't really sound like you want anything more than a collection with a varying number of elements based on the language, so why make classes at all?

Comment: If different verb types need a different set of properties, or need to *behave* differently at runtime, then use the pattern above.

Comment: To address @Magus's point, if you want the compiler to *enforce* properties on each verb conjugation type, you'll want to build these in to each class definition (yes, more work and less flexible, but more safe).  If you don't care, sure just use a dictionary of properties that can be added to dynamically.

Comment: I'm just imagining the number of classes once you've reached the fifth language. `IndicativePresentInLanguagesWithSecondPersonPluralButNotFirstPersonSingular` and it's ilk will only get worse. It will already be a nightmare with a dictionary approach. I'm thinking `[Flags]` enums will be needed to even make fetching and assigning values work.

Comment: Ah sorry, maybe I should have specified - this is *only* for French. I'm building a French linguistic analyzer - the only thing I'm having trouble with is structuring the initial set of data. Since this is only for French, the design will remain (relatively) static once it is in place, and will not need to expand to accommodate other languages (except for UI translations, which are not related to this issue). That being said I currently have one class `VerbConjugation` that has 19 different `structs`. As tenses are not likely to change, is this more maintainable than say, 19 inherited classes?

Comment: To summarize what I've said in my comments and answer, code you write is harder to maintain than code you don't write. Therefore, I'd suggest making a simple enum of tenses, and using it as the key for a dictionary of the words themselves, with one dictionary per root word.

Comment: @Magus - see my edit to the question. If I had 19 `Dictionary` of verb tenses, it would kind of be a nightmare. Each `Word` in a dictionary (that is a verb...), has all 19 of these tenses, with only a single exception. So this pattern needs to be common among all verbs in the dictionary - that is to say that the `VerbConjugation` will be a member of the `Word` class, if the word in the dictionary is a verb. It would be nice to be able to reference a specific conjugation like so: `'suis'` **-->** `VerbConjugation.Indicative.Present.fps` in the `Word` entry of `'etre'`.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: Does the update in my answer meet that requirement well enough?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want, in the end, is a `Dictionary<whicheverenum, string>` rather than a class of data elements.

Lets say we have a verb conjugation which has an IndicativePresent tense:

```
var verb = new Dictionary<IndicativePresent, string>();
if(current == VerbConjugationType.IndicativePresent)
{
  verb[IndicativePresent.FirstPersonSingular] = "whatever";
  ...
}
```

This is all the code you'd need, other than the enum definitions. It's starting to sound like you may actually want a structure of nested dictionaries or even multidimensional arrays (or jagged, more likely). You may be able to get away with either, because enums are integral types. Ultimately, the structure is going to be very complicated, especially if you want the level of chaining you've recently indicated.

You may end up with something like `verb[ConjugationType.Indicative][Tense.Present][Target.FirstPerson][Number.Singular] = "something";` at worst case, at which point designing classes may start to look like a good idea again. The more complicated your data, the harder it is to represent, and few types of data are more complex than grammar.

Comment: could you update your code to show a (specific) example? The flags code is throwing me off and I can't visualize how this would work. I also updated my question with my current code - hopefully it will give you an idea of how I want to be able to access the data.

Comment: In my updated example, there are now four enums. They would be the easy part. It's definitely more wordy than I'd like, and the definition of the dictionary could be rather terrifying.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to move your `VerbConjugation` class members down to a derived `VerbConjugationWithPersons` class. `Participle` and `Imperative` should derive from the former and not the latter.

EDIT: I meant the "persons" class members, of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but you can use inheritance.

```cs
abstract class VerbConjugation {}
class StandardConjugation : VerbConjugation {
  public string firstPersonSingular { get; set; }
  public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
  public string thirdPersonSingular { get; set; }
  public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
  public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
  public string thirdPersonPlural { get; set; }
}
class IndicativePresent : StandardConjugation {}
class IndicativeSimplePast : StandardConjugation {}
class IndicativePresentPerfect : StandardConjugation {}
class Imperative : VerbConjugation 
{
    public string secondPersonSingular { get; set; }
    public string firstPersonPlural { get; set; }
    public string secondPersonPlural { get; set; }
}
class ImperativePast: Imperative {}
class ImperativePresent: Imperative {}
class Participle : VerbConjugation
{
  public string present { get; set; }
  public string past { get; set; }
}
```