# How to get aligned size of CLR blittable struct?

Tags: .net, interop, sizeof

I am making a class similar to [`SafeBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safebuffer.aspx) targetting .NET 2.0. One of the functions is `void ReadArray<T>(long position, T[] array, int offset, int count)` (or `WriteArray`) which reads/writes a series of (blittable) structures into/from an array.

My first guess was to simply use `Marshal.PtrToStructure`/`StructureToPtr` along with advancing by `Marshal.SizeOf`. However looking at the IL for `SafeBuffer.ReadArray` shows it uses `Marshal.AlignedSizeOf<T>()` for advancement (an internal method). That function is defined as:

```
uint s = Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
if (s == 1u || s == 2u || IntPtr.Size == 8 && s == 4u) { return s; }
return Marshal.AlignedSizeOfType(typeof(T)); // an internalcall
```

That method is only defined in .NET 4.0 so is unavailable to me (and also not in Rotor).

My idea was to use `Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement` on adjacent elements in an array but that didn't work. Here is my testing code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct A
        {
            byte a;
            short x;
            byte b;
        }

        private static MethodInfo MarshalAlignedSizeOf;
        static int MAlignedSizeOf(Type t)
        {
            if (MarshalAlignedSizeOf == null) { MarshalAlignedSizeOf = typeof(Marshal).GetMethod("AlignedSizeOf", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static); }
            return (int)(uint)MarshalAlignedSizeOf.MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, null);
        }

        static int AlignedSizeOf(Type t)
        {
            Array a = Array.CreateInstance(t, 0);
            GCHandle pin = GCHandle.Alloc(a, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            try
            {
                return (int)(Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(a, 1).ToInt64() - Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(a, 0).ToInt64());
            }
            finally { pin.Free(); }
        }

        unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("sizeof:       " + sizeof(A));
            Console.WriteLine("SizeOf:       " + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(A)));
            Console.WriteLine("aligned size: " +  AlignedSizeOf(typeof(A)));
            Console.WriteLine("mars algn sz: " + MAlignedSizeOf(typeof(A)));
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs `6, 6, 6,`**`8`** on x86 or x64 (notice how the native AlignedSizeOf is different?).

So the questions are:

1. Discussion: why is this aligned size different than the normal size? In C/C++ sizeof() is the fully aligned value. (`sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` always works)
2. Is there a managed way (with or without unsafe code) to get the aligned size of a blittable generic struct?
3. Should I just be using `SizeOf()` and not care about this extra alignment? In that case I could be just doing a block-transfer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pick option 3, you also don't have access to StructureToPtrNative().  All you can use is Marshal.StructureToPtr() to copy the value type value and that also demands that you use Marshal.SizeOf() to measure it.

That's where the buck stops.  As to the other questions, the exact layout rules that the CLR uses for internal storage are pretty unusual and very hard to reverse engineer.  The size of the example structure when it is stored in an array is indeed 8, two extra bytes of padding are added.  Only 6 is required to get all fields aligned properly.  No idea why it does this, too buried in the CLR internals.  If you want to experiment with the debugger to see this in practice then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241493/17034) shows you how to do that.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var arr = new A[] { new A() { a = 1, x = 2, b = 3}, new A { a = 0x11, x = 0x12, b = 0x13 }};
    }  // <== set breakpoint here
```

And put "&arr" in the debugger memory window's Address box to get

```
 0x000000001D67DE70  98 73 14 03 00 00 00 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 00 00 11 00 12 00 13 00 00 00 
                                             ^ arr[0]                ^ arr[1]
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, I see `01 00 02 00 03 00 11 00 12 00 13 00`. I don't know why I see something different... (tested in both x86 and x64, debug mode, .NET 4). I originally expected to see something like what you have which is why I tried the difference in array element positions.

Comment: That was .NET 3.5.  As I noted, very hard to reverse engineer.

Comment: Still not able to reproduce that alignment pattern, but I guess it is just "implementation magic" in the CLR engine... I will use the `Marshal.SizeOf` and save it that way.